# mysql-client-5.5 update error

Tags: server, apt, dpkg, mysql

I just run `apt-get upgrade` and many packets should be updated. I allowed them all (question after Disk Space and verification). After the download and my configured packages Ubuntu told me from an error in the mysql-client-5.5 update. With `apt-get -f install` this error appears:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mysql-client-5.5
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-client-5.5
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 441 not upgraded.
309 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1891 kB of archives.
After this operation, 37.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  mysql-client-5.5
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
(Reading database ... 74373 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.5_5.5.44-0+deb7u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.44-0+deb7u1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.44-0                                                                                      +deb7u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz', which is also in package                                                                                       mysql-client-core-5.5 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.44-0+deb7u1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried some things like reinstall with the dpkg tool or sth. but nothing worked.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I really need help because I need some things like the webserver with mysql and I'm driving in vacation tomorrow. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, don't use deb files, if the packages can be installed via package manager and don't use debian repositories for no reason.
I assume, you have downloaded the deb from [here](http://pkgs.org/debian-wheezy/debian-security-updates-main-amd64/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.44-0+deb7u1_amd64.deb.html) or a similar side or you have added the line

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-proposed-updates main
```

to your `sources.list`.

Remove this repository and start the commands below

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-client-5.5
```

Comment: And what is suddenly wrong with the answer?